# IP Address Validation with a select input for a mask

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm struggling to find a good solution for verifying an IP address with jQuery Validation.  I have a server side method that will take an Ip Address and subnet mask and let me know if its valid or not however, the webpage has two inputs to put in the IP address Subnetmask combo.

```
<input id="NetworkAddress" class="required" name="NetworkAddress" type="text" value="" />
<select class="required" id="NetworkMask" name="NetworkMask">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="255.255.255.254">31</option>
 <option value="255.255.255.252">30</option>
 ....snip...
</select>
```

Is there some way to assign a single validation rule to both of these inputs.  Because if you enter a network address and then select a networkmask that are invalid a user could possible change either input to fix the address.

For example:

If you type in '10.0.1.0' and select '23' from the drop down you will get an invalid address because that isn't a valid network address for a /23 network.  The user could then change the network address to '10.0.0.0' or they could change the mask to '24' and then the validation would be true, since that is a valid network address with a valid subnet mask. However only one of the errors would be cleared from the form.

I can assign the same remote function to each of the inputs, but it will only give the one that you change a valid class when you change it.  So a user might have to change some text just so the event will fire the client side 'onchange' method to validate the form again.

Once again, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your validation code?

Comment: i'm using the [remote] attribute included with Asp.net MVC 3.  And I do check that the inputs are valid on the server side, but I'm struggling to find a good solution for client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but you should not use this validation just on client side. It is easy to manipulate every data before submit. You should check it on server side and if you want on client side too...

on the client side, you can insert into the select control an empty state, like "Select a value". every time the user changes the input field, you reset the select to the start, which you excactly know cannot be ever valid